# Starting Container in Detached and Interactive Mode Based on ARG Value

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, arguments

I'm working on a project where I have a Docker Compose file with a service definition like this:

```yaml
my-service:
  image: my-image
  command: sh -c 'if [ "$CONTINUOUS_RUN" = "true" ]; then tail -f /dev/null; fi'
```

In my Dockerfile, I have an ARG named `CONTINUOUS_RUN`. If `CONTINUOUS_RUN` is set to `true`, I want the container to start in detached and interactive mode. Otherwise, it should run the specified command and exit.

Here's how I set the ARG in my Dockerfile:

```
# Define an ARG for continuous run
ARG CONTINUOUS_RUN=false
```

My question is: Is there a better or more idiomatic way to achieve this behavior purely using Docker Compose and the Dockerfile without having to modify the command in the Compose file depending on the value of `CONTINUOUS_RUN`? I want to keep the Compose file as clean and declarative as possible.

Comment: you can add `tty: true` to the Docker Compose file

Comment: I want to integrate that with the `CONTINUOUS_RUN` argument how would I be able to do that? Like have `tty: true` if `CONTINUOUS_RUN=true`

Comment: What's the use case for having a container that's only running `tail -f /dev/null`?  In that setup I'd probably just delete the container entirely.  Potentially using the newer [Compose profiles feature](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) can help not start containers that don't need to run.